# Property configuration AEM Day lib

Tags: cookies, aem, osgi-bundle, day-cq

We are using the lib

> "Day Commons Library - HTTP Client 3.1 Bundling
>   (com.day.commons.osgi.wrapper.commons-httpclient)"

in our AEM 6.0 system.
We'd like to change the property `http.protocol.cookie-policy` of this lib to another value. *(It's the cookie policy https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/cookie/CookiePolicy.html).*

**What is the best way to do that?**

The property is not visible in the OSGi console, there are only other values of this lib configurable (like `HTTP Proxy User` etc.)

According to https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/configuring/configuring-osgi.html
one could create a configuration in

> /apps/system/config

But how can we ensure that the library reloads exactly this configuration when we restart the bundle/service in OSGi console?

Does the entry in JCR require to be named like the class

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookiePolicy
```

and the value in the jcr:content has to be of type String and has to contain the other cookie policy, e.g. `BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY`, correct?

How can we determine later if the value was loaded? The problem is: the lib is not our code, we can't simply add a log line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The httpclient osgi bundle loads only select properties defined in [metatype.xml](https://github.com/apache/httpclient/blob/trunk/httpclient5-osgi/src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/metatype/metatype.xml) (This is an example. not the actual config used in day common httpclient). so your config will not be used.

You should be able to use `setCookiePolicy` method of `org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpMethodParams`.